# Can we track html tags visibility in AMP?

Tags: html, amp-html

Let's say I have div block somewhere middle on my web page. When it comes to the viewport, I want to track the visibility in AMP. 
As far as I know, AMP gives provision to track visibility for amp components. Is there any way that I can track the same for HTML tags like div, a, li?

Comment: For what purpose? Analytics, animation, etc. Will be more helpful if you can describe your use case completely.

Comment: It is meant for analytics. For example, if a div block with certain ID comes into the viewport, I want to fire a request to google analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your googleanalytics configuration, set up the trigger with "on":"visible":

```
"triggers": {
    "trigger name": {
        "on": "visible",
        "selector": "#divid",
        ....
     }
     ...
```

See the section on "trigger" for more details:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics#triggers

Comment: but the above code only works for amp components
This is what they have mentioned in the documentation `The element visibility trigger can be configured for any AMP element or a document root using selector`

Comment: "The element can be either an AMP extended element or document root", so I think normal HTML elements (those whitelisted for AMP) should work.